# Why are the probabilities $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta|^2$ when measuring in the computational basis?

Tags: quantum-state, measurement, textbook-and-exercises

In measurement in the computational basis, I was being told that it is a way to extract information from a qubit, and it outputs a classical bit.

For the quantum state $\alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$, the possible outputs are:

$0$, with probability $|\alpha|^2$ and

$1$, with probability $|\beta|^2$.

Why are the probabilities $|\alpha|^2$ and $|\beta|^2$? I assume this is related to the figure below? (where $\alpha$ being the possibilities for it to fall in the x-axis and $\beta$ for the y-axis?)

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need to read some basic books about Quantum Mechanics. For example, maybe [nielsen's](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf) chapter 2 is enough for you. In quantum mechanics, the probability is always connected to the $\mid\cdot\mid^2$. It's a basic assumption.

Comment: @narip Sure, thanks for the recommendation. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **postulate** or axiom of quantum mechanics that if a state $|\psi\rangle $ that is a linear superposition of eigenstates $\{ |e_i\rangle\}$ of some observable,
$$ |\psi \rangle = \sum_i \alpha_i |e_i\rangle $$
then upon making measurement *with respect to this observable*, the state is observed in the state $|e_i\rangle$ with probability $|a_i|^2$. That is, $P(|e_i\rangle) = |a_i|^2$. Also note that $\sum |\alpha_i|^2 = 1$ is a necessary condition.

In quantum computing, when we talk about measurement, it usually correspond to measuring in the computational or Z basis. So for a single qubit system, your observable would be the single Pauli Z matrix, $Z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$, which has eigenvectors of $|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and  $|1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $.

Now, your state is $|\psi \rangle = 0.6|0\rangle + 0.8|1\rangle $ is already written as the linear combination of the eigenstates of the Pauli Z matrix. And thus, the probability to observe $|0\rangle$ is $|0.6|^2$, that is, $P(|0\rangle ) = |0.6|^2$.  Similarly, $P(|1\rangle) = |0.8|^2$.